# how to make a load of states maintainable in functional components in react?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a functional component, including some states.
I've declared them separately like this :

```
const [categoryState, setCategoryState] = useState("");
const [titleState, setTitleState] = useState("");
const [descriptionState, setDescriptionState] = useState("");
.
.
.
```

the list goes on, I think it's not that maintainable, So I'm looking for a way to handle them in best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all, your approach is not wrong**. I like to have separate `useState` hooks for values that usually don't change together.

*If* you really want to consolidate the state, you have a couple of options:

**Option 1: Use single `useState()` and combine values into 1 object**

```
const [article, setArticle] = useState({
  title: '',
  category: '',
  description: ''
});


const updateCategory = (newCategory) => {
  setArticle({
    ...article,
    category: newCategory
  })
}
```

**Option 2: Use useReducer**

```
const initialState = {title: '', description: '', category: ''};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_TITLE':
      return {
        ...state,
        title: action.title
      };
    case 'SET_DESCRIPTION':
      return {
        ...state,
        description: action.description
      };
    case 'SET_CATEGORY':
      return {
        ...state,
        category: action.category
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}



// and in your component:
const YourComponent = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    return (
        <>
            Title: {state.title}
            Description: {state.description}
            Category: {state.category}
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'SET_TITLE', title: 'This is a new title'});}>Update Title</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'SET_CATEGORY', category: 'This is a new category'});}>Update Category</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'SET_DESCRIPTION', description: 'This is a new description'});}>Update Description</button>
        </>
    )
    
}
```

I think you should use the approach that you find to be the least awkward when reading or updating your state.

Remember, you don’t need to combine all state into 1 object. It makes sense to have logical separations of state, each with their own useState or useReducer hook.

Comment: The second approach is what I needed for this specific component, I've tried it, works perfectly. thanks for sharing your knowledge.